# SQL CASE in SELECT clause

Tags: sql-server-2014

I need to add a concatenated field to my SELECT clause based on the results of my WHERE clause. Here is my current query:

```
Declare
@Low numeric(13,0) = 10000,
@High numeric(13,0) = 100000000000,
@Name varchar(100) = '%',
@Stname varchar(100) = '%georgia',
@Sumlev varchar(3) = 1,
@County varchar(30) = 123456,
@Place varchar (5) = 8,
@Gid2 varchar(5),
@Gid2_1 varchar (7);

if object_id('tempdb..#GeoID2') is not null drop table #GeoID2

SELECT
    SUMLEV, State, County, Place, Name, Stname, ESTIMATESBASE2010, CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(STATE)) + STATE, REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(COUNTY)) + COUNTY) AS Gid2
INTO
    #GeoID2
FROM
    [CensusData].[dbo].[SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE
    (NOT (SUMLEV = @Sumlev)) AND (NOT (County = @County)) AND (NOT (PLACE = @Place)) AND 
              (ESTIMATESBASE2010 > @Low) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 < @High) AND (Name LIKE @Name) and (Stname LIKE @Stname)

SELECT
    [#GeoID2].SUMLEV, [#GeoID2].State, [#GeoID2].County, [#GeoID2].Place, [#GeoID2].Stname, [#GeoID2].Name, [#GeoID2].ESTIMATESBASE2010, [ACS_14_5YR_S1901_with_ann].[HC01_EST_VC13] as Avg_Salary, [#GeoID2].Gid2, [#GeoID2].Gid21
FROM
    [CensusData].[dbo].[#GeoID2] INNER JOIN
    [CensusData].[dbo].[ACS_14_5YR_S1901_with_ann] ON [CensusData].[dbo].[#GeoID2].Gid2 = [CensusData].[dbo].[ACS_14_5YR_S1901_with_ann].[GEO id2]
ORDER BY
    [#GeoID2].NAME
```

I need to add a CASE statement to my first SELECT clause to assign a value to Gid2. The current value is assigned as:

```
CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(STATE)) + STATE, REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(COUNTY)) + COUNTY) AS Gid2
```

What I need to do is check the value of [County] before I assign this value. Based on that result I will use one of two formulas. Here is what I tried (that does not work):

```
Case
    When (County = 0)
    Then 'CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(STATE)) + STATE, REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(PLACE)) + PLACE) AS Gid2'
    Else 'CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(STATE)) + STATE, REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(COUNTY)) + COUNTY) AS Gid2'
End
```

I am not sure that using CASE is the right way to go, but I can't figure out any other way to approach this. Can someone help?

Comment: To start with, in your case statement the "as Gid2" should come after the "end"

Comment: FWIW, I think it's fine to use a CASE statement for something like this.

Comment: Brian - good point on "as Gid2", i moved that after "end", but i am still getting an error: Incorrect syntax near '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I was using ' in front of my Concat function when I should have been using (. Here is a working query:

```
Declare
@Low numeric(13,0) = 10000,
@High numeric(13,0) = 100000000000,
@Name varchar(100) = '%',
@Stname varchar(100) = '%georgia',
@Sumlev varchar(3) = 1,
@County varchar(30) = 123456,
@Place varchar (5) = 8,
@Gid2 varchar(5),
@Gid2_1 varchar (7);

if object_id('tempdb..#GeoID2') is not null drop table #GeoID2

SELECT
SUMLEV, State, County, Place, Name, Stname, ESTIMATESBASE2010,

Case
    When (County = 0)
    Then (CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(STATE)) + STATE, REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(PLACE)) + PLACE))
    Else (CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(STATE)) + STATE, REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(COUNTY)) + COUNTY))
End AS Gid2

 INTO
    #GeoID2

FROM
    [CensusData].[dbo].[SUB-EST2014_ALL]

WHERE
    (NOT (SUMLEV = @Sumlev)) AND (NOT (County = @County)) AND (NOT (PLACE = @Place)) AND 
              (ESTIMATESBASE2010 > @Low) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 < @High) AND (Name LIKE @Name) and (Stname LIKE @Stname)

SELECT
    [#GeoID2].SUMLEV, [#GeoID2].State, [#GeoID2].County, [#GeoID2].Place, [#GeoID2].Stname, [#GeoID2].Name, [#GeoID2].ESTIMATESBASE2010, [ACS_14_5YR_S1901_with_ann].[HC01_EST_VC13] as Avg_Salary, [#GeoID2].Gid2

FROM
    [CensusData].[dbo].[#GeoID2] INNER JOIN
    [CensusData].[dbo].[ACS_14_5YR_S1901_with_ann] ON [CensusData].[dbo].[#GeoID2].Gid2 = [CensusData].[dbo].[ACS_14_5YR_S1901_with_ann].[GEO id2]

ORDER BY
    [#GeoID2].NAME
```

Comment: Very nice! When you get a chance to accept your own answer, please do so. That will bring closure to your question.